# Can we fix the link at the start of the When Is An Account “Abandoned” blog post?

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, blog

The [When Is An Account “Abandoned”?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/02/16/when-is-an-account-abandoned/) blog post begins:

> [image]

Now, if you (like me) are reading this post for the first time, this is rather confusing: it says question deletion "works this way", which since there is no link is (incorrectly) interpreted as the same way that account deletion works.

**Question**: Can we fix the link at the start of the When Is An Account “Abandoned” blog post?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to insert a link there. That is the automatically generated excerpt, which always takes the plain-text version of the article to remove paragraphs and other formatting to create such an excerpt. [This one](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/06/new-10k-rep-tools-now-available/) does the same thing, it's just a bit less awkward to read without the link.